# Can I include the unit vectors when I represent a vector in matrix form?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Assuming vector $A=a_1i + a_2j + a_3k$. Can I represent it as:

$[a_1i, a_2j, a_3k]$?

I don't see the unit vectors included in the matrix form of a vector in many examples I read from books, but I think this is because its inclusion is nontrivial. Is the above matrix also valid?

Comment: When writing a vector in coordinate form, the elements are numbers, not vectors.  You have written a matrix of vectors.  What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Hi @saulspatz, when we perform a dot product, we do something like:

a⋅b=(a1i+a2j+a3k)⋅(b1i+b2j+b3k)=a1b1i⋅i+a2b2j⋅j+a3b3k⋅k+(a1b2+a2b1)i⋅j+(a1b3+a3b1)i⋅k+(a2b3+a3b2)j⋅k


But since i⋅j, j⋅j, j⋅k are all equal to zero, the operation is reduced to:

a⋅b = a1b1i⋅i+a2b2j⋅j+a3b3k⋅k

I feel that the same operation should be carried out if the vectors are represented in matrix form. But since the dot product of the unit vectors is either equal to 0 or 1, their representation are omitted in the matrix form.

Comment: Is $[ai, bj, ck]$ different from $[aj, bi, ck]$?

Comment: Hi @saulspatz, I edited my answer above. Hopefully youd be able to understand what I've written. I am new to stack.exchange and I'm having hard time with formatting. Thank you for spending some time on my question.

Comment: @JohnCampus For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you, @soupless!